# Gmail Label Search for Parent Label (including all its children)

Tags: gmail, search, gmail-search

GMail has some great features, one of which is label tagging to organize your inbox. However, I have a situation where I stuff all "waste of time" emails that sometimes I peruse into the following label structure:

Entertainment
Entertainment/Politics
Entertainment/Twitter
Entertainment/etc...

So, I can easily search `"has label:Entertainment/Facebook"` although I would rather be able to search `"has label:Facebook"`

But, most of all, I'd really like to be able to search for ALL Entertainment emails at once, like

```
"has label:Entertainment*"
```

Unfortunately... GMail does not support wildcard (*, %) nor "nested" labels (I know they aren't actually nested).

Is this literally impossible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain.  If you nest a label one would assume (prefer) that the parent label inherits the child label, but as you've noted, it does not.

A common solution is to add another filter that catches all the same messages as combining the 'child' labels into a single filter would.

```
Mail Filter 1:
   from:(johnnyteacher@domain.com) 
   Label: school/sonselementary

Mail Filter 2:
   from:(sallyteacher@domain.com) 
   Label: school/sallyssecondary

Mail Filter 3 (1 & 2 Combined):
   from:(johnnyteacher@domain.com) OR from:(sallyteacher@domain.com) 
   Label: school
```

This does the trick however becomes very difficult to manage over time. You need to remember to update rules in several places.  You might have child labels that are themselves parent labels and the complexity becomes overwhelming.

I started building an Excel spreadsheet that creates the code for the rules for me and also manages the relationship between parents, children and siblings.  It hasn't been without it's own 'learnings' along the way and I will likely try to finish it using a more DB/scripting approach as I am stretching Excel into shapes it doesn't look good in.

It is a huge advantage to me to delete and recreate rules as (1) you can update multiple rules quickly, (2) you can apply multiple rules quickly (i.e. Gmail asks if you'd like to apply them as part of the import process, (3)  you can reorder your rules simply by deleting and reimporting your rules in a new order if you strip out unique identifiers before import.  I have preferences for my order unrelated to when the rule was created.

### Edit 2023-11-15

I wrote a Google Apps Script and posted it on GitHub in late 2021.  I been using it myself continuously since then.

Excerpt from **[gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label > README.md](https://github.com/CaTeNdrE/gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label/blob/main/README.md)**:

> ### [gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label](https://github.com/CaTeNdrE/gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label)
>
> Google Apps Script that adds ancestors' labels to Gmail messages labeled with one of their descendants.
>
> The goal of this script is to create a Gmail label search experience more akin to a directory search without having to duplicate and combine filter rules.
>
> Gmail's custom user labels can be nested below one another and Gmail displays labels in the menu in a way that closely mimics a computer's directory structure. Unlike a search on a computer, when searching a label Gmail does not automatically include its descendants.
>
> This script was developed because my preferred default approach to searching within labels is to 'include' rather than 'exclude' their descendants.

### Script

Get latest version at **[GitHub > gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label](https://github.com/CaTeNdrE/gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label)**

```
/**
 * 
 *   +----------------------------------------+
 *   |  GAS Gmail Add Parent of Nested Label  |
 *   +----------------------------------------+ 
 *   
 *   rev. 2023-06-27
 *   rev. 2021-11-17
 *   
 *   https://github.com/CaTeNdrE/gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label
 *   
 *  
 *   Google Action Script (GAS) that searches Gmail messages in nested
 *   user labels and applies their parent label if it is missing.
 * 
 *   Ensures that a Gmail labeled with:
 *     
 *   "sport/hockey"     is also in "sport"
 *   "sport/basketball" is also in "sport"
 *   "sport/lax/field"  is also in "sport" as well as "sport/lax"
 * 
 *   Skip Lists are used to exclude labels from this behavior.  
 *   A label can be excluded by both lists without causing any issues.
 */

//    Offsprint Skip List
//  +-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  | Array of labels whose offspring (children, grandchildren, etc.) 
//  | will be excluded from syncing. To also exclude the actual labels 
//  | in this list, they must also be added to the "Labels Skip List". 
//  +----------------------------------------------------------------- 
      const offspring = [
 //       "Sync Issues",
 //       "mymessages",
 //       "theOffspring",    // eg. Non-existent Ancestor  
 //       "INBOX"            // eg. System Label
      ];

//    Labels Skip List
//  +------------------------------------------------------ 
//  | Array of individual labels to exclude from syncing to 
//  | their parents, grandparents, great-grandparents, etc.
//  +------------------------------------------------------
      const skiplabel = [
//        "SENT",               // eg. System Label
//        "noLabelsPlease",     // eg. Non-existent label       
//        "notReal/andWrong"    // eg. Non-existent label
      ];

//    Log Level (loglevel) 
//  +--------------------------------------------- 
//  | 1 = info [default], 2 = verbose,  3 - debug)
//  +---------------------------------------------  
      const loglevel = 1; 


/**
 *    +---------------------------------+
 *    |                                 | 
 *    |  Be careful editing below here  |
 *    |                                 | 
 *    +---------------------------------+ 
 */

const logs = {};
const pad = {};
const list = {};
const len = {};
// const namesList = [];
const names = { All: [], System: [], List: []  };
const sp = String.fromCharCode(160); // define a non-breaking space for use as needed.
const padDef = 3;          // default number padding
const skiplog = { 
  Name: [], Type: [], Output: [], Count: 0
};

/** 
 *    +------------------+
 *    |  addParentLabel  |
 *    +------------------+
 */

function addParentLabel() {

  if (!([1, 2, 3].indexOf(loglevel) > -1)) {
    loglevel = 1;
  }

  mylabels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me').labels;
  mylabels.forEach(thisLabel => names.All.push(thisLabel.name));

  let labelcount = names.All.length.toString();
  let padnum = labelcount.length;
  
  let fetchlog = labelcount.padStart(padnum) + " GMAIL labels retrieved";
  let uline = '\n' + "-".padEnd(fetchlog.length, "-");
  fetchlog +=  uline;

  if (loglevel > 2) {
    let line = 0;
    mylabels.forEach(thisLabel => console.log((++line).toString().padStart(padDef)
      + sp + thisLabel));
  }
  
  //  System labels
  list.System = mylabels.filter(thisLabel => thisLabel.type == "system");
  list.System.forEach(thisLabel => names.System.push(thisLabel.name));
  
  fetchlog += '\n' + list.System.length.toString().padStart(padnum) + " are system labels";

  //  User labels with no parent
  len.orphan = (list.orphan = mylabels.filter(
    thisLabel => (!(thisLabel.name.search("/") > 0) && thisLabel.type == "user")
    )).length.toString();    

  fetchlog += '\n' + len.orphan.padStart(padnum) + " have no parent";

  //  In a skip list and match a valid label 
  const relevant = mylabels.filter(
    thisLabel => thisLabel.name.search("/") > 0
      && thisLabel.type == "user"
      && matchLabel(thisLabel.name, skiplabel, offspring, padDef) > 0
  );    

  if (relevant.length) {
    fetchlog += '\n' + relevant.length.toString().padStart(padnum)
    + " match skip lists"
  };

  //  User label has parent and not excluded by a skip list  
  const valid = mylabels.filter(
    thisLabel => thisLabel.type == "user" 
      && thisLabel.name.search("/") > 0 
      && matchLabel(thisLabel.name, skiplabel, offspring, padDef, 1) == 0
      );
  len.Valid = valid.length.toString();
  

  fetchlog += uline + '\n' + len.Valid.padStart(padnum)
    + " user labels to search";
 
  Logger.log(fetchlog);

  if (skiplog.Name.length) { thisPad = getPadding(skiplog.Name, 3)};  
    
  
  
  // validate skip lists 
  if (offspring.length) validate(offspring, "Offspring", padnum);  
  if (skiplabel.length) validate(skiplabel, "Labels", padnum);

  // List  matching user labels if loglevel > 1 
  if (loglevel > 1) {

    for (let i = 0; i < skiplog.Name.length; i++) {
    skiplog.Output += (skiplog.Name[i].padEnd(thisPad, sp) + skiplog.Type[i] + '\n'); 
  };

    let txt = "Gmail User Labels that matched a Skip List";
    Logger.log(txt + '\n' + "-".padEnd(txt.length, "-") + '\n' + skiplog.Output);
  };
   
  valid.forEach(thisLabel => names.List.push(thisLabel.name));
  names.List.sort();
  let padname = getPadding(names.List, 1);    // length of longest string plus x sps (or 1 if omitted);
  checking = "Checking messages in " + len.Valid + " labels"; 
  Logger.log(checking + (loglevel > 1 ? logLabels(names.List, checking.length, padname) : ""));

/**
 *    +-----------------+
 *    |  Search Emails  |
 *    +-----------------+
 */

  for (let i = 0; i < len.Valid; i++) {
    
    let label = valid[i].name;

    // Parent label's Gmail ID (retrieve using index from name)
    let thisParent = label.replace("/" + label.split("/").pop(), "");
    let thisParentIndex = mylabels.findIndex(thisIndex => thisIndex.name == thisParent); 
    let thisParentId = mylabels[thisParentIndex].id;

    
    let thisQuery = "\-label:" + thisParent + " label:" + label; // this label but not its parent

    let msgList = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", { "q": thisQuery }).messages;  // list of matching messages
  
    if (msgList) {
      var allUpdates = +1;
      let thisLog = "";
    
      for (let j = 0; j < msgList.length; j++) {  // for each msg in list
        let msgNum = +j + 1;
        let msgId = msgList[j].id;
        let addLabel = thisParentId;
        thisLog += msgNum.toString().padStart(padDef, sp) + sp + "\"" + thisParent + "\"" + sp + "added" + sp + "to" + sp + "msgID" + sp + msgId.padEnd(17, sp) + " ";
      
        Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(
          {
            'addLabelIds': [addLabel]
          },
            'me', msgId
        );
      };

      let thisLogPad = + padDef + 40 + (msgList.length > 1 ? 2 : 0) + label.length + thisParent.length;
      Logger.log(msgList.length.toString().padStart(padDef, sp) + sp + (msgList.length > 1 ? "messages" : "message") + sp + "with \"" + label + "\"" + sp + (msgList.length > 1 ? "were" : "was") + sp + "missing the label \"" + thisParent + "\"" + (loglevel > 1 ? '\n' + "--".padEnd(thisLogPad, "-") + '\n' + thisLog : ""));
    
    }; 

  };

  if (!allUpdates) Logger.log("All labelled messages included the labels of their ancestors");  

}



/**
 *    +--------------+
 *    |  Log Labels  |
 *    +--------------+
 */

function logLabels(arr, num, pad) {
  let log = '\n' + ("-").padEnd(num, "-") + '\n';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let label = (i + 1).toString().padStart(padDef, sp) + sp + 
    arr[i].replaceAll(' ', sp).padEnd(pad);
    log += label;
  }
  return log;
}


/**
 *    +-----------------------+
 *    |  Skip List Validation |
 *    +-----------------------+
 */

function validate(list, name, pad) {
  
  let len = list.length;
  let log = len.toString().padStart(pad) + (len == 1 ? " entry" : " entries")  + " in " + name + " skip list"

  let nomatch = list.filter(thisLabel => names.All.indexOf(thisLabel) == -1);
  let system = list.filter(thisLabel => names.System.includes(thisLabel));
  let nl = nomatch.length, sl = system.length;

  (nl || sl) && (log += '\n' + "-".padEnd(log.length, "-")); 
    
  if (nl) {

    log +=  '\n' + nl.toString().padStart(pad) + (nl > 1 ? " don't" : " doesn't") + " exist:";

    for (let i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
      
      ([i] < 1) && (log += ("[").padStart(pad, sp));
      log += sp + nomatch[i];
      (([i] == (nl - 1)) && (log += " ]")) || (log += ","); 

    };

  };

  if (sl) {

    log +=  '\n' + sl.toString().padStart(pad) + (sl > 1 ? " are system labels" : " is a system label") + " and ignored:";

    for (let i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
      
      ([i] < 1) && (log += ("[").padStart(pad, sp));
      log += sp + system[i];
      (([i] == (sl - 1)) && (log += " ]")) || (log += ","); 

    };

  };

  Logger.log(log);

}


/**
 *    +-----------------------+
 *    |  matchLabel Function  |
 *    +-----------------------+
 */

function matchLabel(strVal, arrVal, arrDes, padDef, log, pad) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arrDes.length; i++) {

    if (strVal.startsWith(arrDes[i] + "/")) {

      if (log == 1) {
        skiplog.Count += 1;
        skiplog.Name.push(skiplog.Count.toString().padStart(padDef) + sp + strVal);
        skiplog.Type.push(("Ancestor:" + sp + arrDes[i]).replaceAll(' ', sp));
      }
      return 1;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arrVal.length; i++) {
      if (strVal == arrVal[i]) {
        if (log == 1) {
          skiplog.Count += 1;
          skiplog.Name.push(skiplog.Count.toString().padStart(padDef) + sp + strVal.replaceAll(' ', sp));
          skiplog.Type.push("Labels Skip List".replaceAll(' ', sp));
        }
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

/**
 *    +--------------------+
 *    |  Padding Function  |
 *    +--------------------+
 */

// returns length of longest string in array for column padding 
function getPadding(list, extra) {     
  if (!extra) extra = 1;         // define 'extra' spaces if not set
  if (!Array.isArray(list)) {    // if string, convert to array
    var oldList = list;
    var newValue = "x";
    var list = [list, newValue];
    Logger.log("**  Type Error: \"" + oldList + "\" was a String. Now converted to Array \"" + list + "\"");
  }

  if (list.length) {
      var longest = list.reduce(function (a, b) // determine longest string in the array
        { return a.length > b.length ? a : b; });
  };

  var padding = longest.length + extra; // set padding as longest string plus 'extra' spaces
  return padding;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. A sad day indeed. But - thank you for this solution and I like where you are going with the automated rule generator. You might consider making this a GMail plugin if it exposes enough via their API (which I've not looked into yet). Then you could actually publish it as a plugin - just a thought. :)

Comment: I'll post something back if I get that far.  :-)

Comment: @Gr3go my rule generator adventure has exposed challenges/limitations of generalizing it to other users' needs.  HTML Gmail's search syntax is limited.  Complicated searches, if achievable, have a high character count which is amplified if combined in parent filters.  Combined searches are fraught with error paths even with insight into the needs and the syntax.  I continue to evolve my approach as I learn more. I am trying a different approach using scripting to avoid some of the pitfalls. I'll update.

Comment: This must be why one doesn't already exist after all these years... I do hope it is possible. I feel it would be a great plug in.

Comment: Might as well add my lamenting voice to this chorus. Ugh. Would love a "label-parent:" filter in my search.