# Gmail Filters Length Limits in XML File

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Gmail has limits to the length of filter queries that seems to be tied to mail's 'search' feature. If the filter 'To' category has a list of addresses separated by an OR operator, Gmail will give the message

> The specified search is too long. Please specify shorter advanced search criteria.

The filter does not apply although Gmail does not notify the user and can save the filter. It will not work as a filter and the only way to identify the issue is when searching the filter selection criteria, where at that point you get the error message. If I were to modify an XML file to create Gmail filters, will the limitation on search length still apply?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please try it and share with us your findings.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Yes: Limit also applies to XML</s>    **>  *! See footnote !* <**

---

### NO-ish

After running some tests I can confirm that:

1. Gmail allows you to manually import custom xml filters that 'greatly' exceed the character limit imposed if you tried to create them in the GUI.
2. Those imported filters cannot be edited in the GUI.  Attempting to edit one will trigger the "...search is too long..." error.
3. 'Some' of these imported filters actually 'work'.

I quote ('') the words 'some' and 'work' because I can't yet confirm if the 'working' filters, 'fully' work, or the non-working filters, work in some capacity.

I couldn't find any documentation around this.  I found it very time consuming to properly test success and error paths while also documenting.  This is of course compounded by the huge character/word counts.  I've been trying to use an initial methodology based on a principal of 'all-other-things-being-equal' (except the character count).  I'm hoping my approach limits the number of new undocumented 'features' I trip over.

It may simply come down to orders of magnitude however I've noted inconsistencies where higher character count searches 'work' while lower count searches appear not to.

I will post an update when I learn anything more.

---

### Google Apps Script (GAS) Option

This testing to extract more information from Gmail Search's 'black box' will likely yield helpful information in addition to more unanswered questions.

I went down this same rabbit hole previously while building an Excel-based solution for creating custom XML filters.  It was prompted by another poster's question "[StackEchange/Web Applications/Gmail Label Search for Parent Label](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159211/gmail-label-search-for-parent-label-including-all-its-children/159258#159258)", which mirrored my own needs.

I found at the time that every cleared hurdle led to a new hurdle ahead, and they seemed to get higher each time.  I ultimately cobbled together my first **Goggle Apps Script** solution .

If you have an ordered minded you may find it valuable to open that box.  GAS is Javascript-based (both of which I was new to), and is extremely well documented by both Google and the Community.  Not to mention the large quantity of good documentation specific to Javascript itself.  I made my first script in October 2021 for managing labels that I wanted to nest.  If I can do it, I expect many many other people can.

I posted my GAS for nested labels to [github: gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label 2021-Nov](https://github.com/CaTeNdrE/gas-gmail-add-parent-of-nested-label) so the OP and anyone else interested could access it.  It assumes a limited knowledge of GAS, Javascript, and Github, and includes detailed instructions.

It should still work properly.  I have changed my own version since then so will update the repository at some point.

Outside of the character count, I don't know what you are trying to do so this may or may not be helpful.

---

### Footnote

Originally I would have said (did say) NO.  I was very confident given my own efforts less that a year ago to do the same.  I was glib in my comment when downvoted (since deleted).

When [@glorfindel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/136642/glorfindel) gave me the benefit of the doubt but suggested my response could benefit from 'Official References' I dug deeper.

I believed it was pointless, but couldn't comfortably state that 'absolutely' without proof.  As I expected, I failed to find any useful documentation, so created some tests to use to prove my point. This 'proof' has now turned into my penance for a lack of initial rigor, documentation, and humility as I proved myself wrong. I will complete testing it to the best of my ability and post results for back.

Big thank you to [@glorfindel](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/136642/glorfindel).  Also glad I didn't dig myself a deeper hole :-)

Comment: I don't doubt you're right (I didn't downvote) but this answer could do with some official references.