# Gmail "superset" label?

Tags: gmail

Let's say I have the label `Lists/A`, `Lists/B`, `Lists/C`, etc.

How can I search for all messages tagged with `Lists/<anything>`?

Answer (score 1):

You must list all labels in which you want to search.

Example: "label:{Lists Lists-A Lists-B Lists-C}"

Unfortunately, parent labels do not automatically include any of the content labeled with children. The nesting is visual only.

More information found here in a related post: [Gmail Label Search for Parent Label (including all its children)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159211/gmail-label-search-for-parent-label-including-all-its-children/159258#159258)